# query for Math.random to generate only a certain amount of each number needed

Tags: java, math, random

I am curious if anyone knows a way to use `math.random` to generate random numbers between say 0 and 3, But when it generates two 0's or two 1's it rules out the possibility of generating them numbers?

This is for a game assignment for college and all I have left to do is set it that it only generates two of each number with one 3. If anyone knows how this would be very helpful (even if it is using something other than `math.random`.

The language is Java.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: In which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to keep track of the number draws, right?

A possible solution is to use an array whose length is the valid range of your random numbers, where each cell counts the occurrences of the respective number. Then, for each draw, you check the contents of the respective cell in the array to see if you reached the limit. If you did, then redraw and repeat.

Note: at the time of writing this, the language of use is unknown, but the solution is generic enough to be implemented in virtually any language that provide a random() function.

Comment: OK, So what I done was make each value from 1-9 equal a different image my game needed, I then used math random to generate random numbers from 1 to 9 but not letting it repeat a number. Is this good coding or should I have went about it a completely different way?

Comment: @Roymcloughlin - it is hard to follow. Update your question with a code snippet.